# Do there exist algorithms for which the Big-O cannot be found out?

Tags: time-complexity

Just out of curiosity:

Do there exist algorithms for which the Big-O cannot be found out?

I have done a quick search in the google search bar:
"Big o, impossible to evaluate"
"algorithms without big o"

And these gave results which were unsatisfactory. Mostly, teaching me how to find the big o. Nothing I haven't learned earlier.

On a side note, it is my understanding that finding the big o requires us to assume the worst possible case. But, is that always a correct metric for efficiency? What is the likelihood a function is called with the worst possible argument?

Comment: _"big o requires us to assume the worst possible case"_ ... no, the $O$ notation is used for giving the worst case running time of an algorithm.  You can also use [average-case complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity) analysis.

Answer (score 4):

There are some algorithms for which, as of today, we are not able to prove termination, much less to bound complexity.

A simple case is given by the [Collatz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3x_%2B_1_problem): in pseudocode

```
function Collatz(n):
  if n <= 1  then return 1
  if even n then return 1 + Collatz(n/2)
  return 1 + Collatz(3*n + 1)
```

It is believed that, for any natural $n$, `Collatz(n)` will eventually stop recursing. However, we do not know whether this is is the case. Consequently, we also do not know an upper bound for the time complexity of this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the order of complexity can be described as typical, best case and worst case.  That complexity is normally expressed in terms of compute time, but could also be expressed in terms of memory utilization.

Big omega is commonly used to denote lower bound.

Big theta is commonly used to denote two sided bounds.

With respect to the aspect of your question around whether there are algorithms which cannot be characterized .. I would suggest that there are algorithms which are suitably complex, and who's performance has a very wide range of performance observations so as to not readily be characterizable.  However, I am not aware of a proof that there are a class of algorithms which are uncharacterizable.

Comment: $O$ is an upper bound. $\Omega$ is a lower bound, with [two different definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). *$\Theta$ is a two-sided bound* (both $O$ and $\Omega$), not an upper one.

Comment: @Thumbnail, you are correct. I have edited accordingly.  I forget this stuff after 40 years. Blush.